# Can there be created a different firmware for mother boards different than DOS

Tags: hardware, ms-dos, firmware

Maybe this is a dumb question but is something I need to know.
All laptops, computers, etc that i've used until today runs DOS as bios firmware... So I was wondering if there is motherboards running firmware that it is not DOS...?

Answer (score 7):

You are a bit confused, I will try and keep this simple:

[DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) is an [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) mainstreamed by Microsoft.

[BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bios) is an operating system (arguably) of very limited nature, that is typically stored as firmware on a motherboard. It is far less functional and complex, it just to "get things going" with relation to the hardware inside a computer, before starting up a boot loader.

[BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bios) is being phased out for [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) these days.

Answer (score 3):

No mainboard uses [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) as a firmware. What you mean is the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). It's gradually replaced by [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface), which I would consider a mixed blessing.

Non X86-Mainboards use/used entirely different system like [OpenFirmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFirmware).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @javano and @SvenW but fast .... backward a few years and the question may not be so irrelevant. In the days of MS-DOS 3.x and before the BIOS was so custom made (with hooks) for MS-DOS that using it with another OS was virtually impossible. But then there was no other OS in those days other than MS-DOS not on that platform anyway (i86-i386). Just a bit of history...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit saddened by the fact you seem to associate a character based interface with DOS. (most server operating systems have nothing else).

But it is true most PC systems still start up in 8-bit mode before switching to full 32/64-bit. All this is mainly for compatibility reasons.

The [Coreboot FAQ](http://www.coreboot.org/FAQ)  is quite an interesting read. This project allows you to replace your manufacturer BIOS with Linux for faster boot times and other more powerful features.